# concatenate two fields of mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have fields in mysql database table caps that are `imgpath` and `imgname`. My image path is `images/man/caps/` and image name is `sun-cap.png`. Now what I want to pick both of them via this query

```
select imgpath, imgname from caps;
```

Now how to concatenate them and display it in php so the output be might like this

> images/man/caps/sun.cap.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use it as

```
$result = mysql_query('select concat(imgpath, imgname) as img from caps');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo $row['img'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select concat(imgpath, imgname) as img from caps;
```

Comment: @sajid You need to read [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 select concat(imgpath, imgname) from caps;
```

Comment: i echo it like this '  if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        //Fetch rows
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      
   $imgurl=$row['imgpath']['imgname'];
   echo "<div class='prodimages' >";
   echo "<img src='$imgurl' alt='$text'/>";'     but not working

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the concatenated string from MySQL itself like stated by @xdazz then simply echo it like

```
echo $row['img'];
```

else if you are using query like `select imgpath, imgname from caps;` use

```
echo $row['imgpath'].$row['imgname'];
```